# Call to undefined method Sendgrid::send() in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, sendgrid

I am using sendgrid api v3. Everything works fine on my localserver with core php and now i move my code on server with codeigniter framework. It shows me following error.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Sendgrid::send() in /var/www/html/adihex/application/helpers/sendgrid_helper.php on line 19

Here is my code

```
<?php
require_once FCPATH . 'sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php';

function send_mail()
{
    $template_id = '********************************';
    $api_key = '*************************************';
    // echo '<pre>';
    $email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();
    $email->setFrom("test@example.com", "Example User");
    $email->setSubject("Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun");
    $email->addTo("singhrobin1238014@gmail.com", "Example User");
    $email->setTemplateId($template_id);
    $email->addDynamicTemplateDatas([
        'heading'     => 'Welcome to Adihex',
    ]);
    $sendgrid = new \SendGrid($api_key);
    try {
        $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
        print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
        print_r($response->headers());
        print $response->body() . "\n";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    }
}
```

Please guide me where i am wrong.
Any solution appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Although its late but it might help someone ,

You might be having Multiple Classes with same name , SendGrid In this case the script is searching for send function in someother Class with same name,